# Does PBC (pairing-based cryptography library) support curve25519?

Tags: cryptography, curve-25519

I don't know how to input a point at curve25519 using pbc.

If not, how can I calculate pairing points at curve25519?

Is there any other lib solving this?

Comment: What makes you think that Curve25519 can be used for pairing-based cryptography? You need a pairing-friendly curve which Curve25519 is not. Maybe it is possible, but it would be horribly slow.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for your help. I modified the transaction protocol of Monero (a cryptocurrency) which uses curve25519 so I need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curve25519 is not pairing-friendly.

There are two famous libraries about pairing: [MIRACL](https://www.miracl.com/) and [pbc](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/).